# How to populate a column with a value if condition is met across 2+ other colums

Tags: pandas, if-statement, lambda

My dataframe is similar to the table below. I have 6 columns, each with 'Yes' or 'No' if a specific antibiotic was given.

| AZITH | CLIN | CFTX | METRO | CFTN | DOXY | TREATED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | Yes | No | No | No | No |  |
| No | Yes | No | Yes | No | No |  |
| Yes | Yes | No | No | No | No |  |
| No | No | No | No | No | No |  |
| Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |  |
| No | Yes | Yes | Yes | No | Yes |  |
| No | No | No | No | No | Yes |  |
| No | No | No | No | No | No |  |
| Yes | Yes | Yes | No | No | No |  |
| Yes | No | Yes | Yes | No | No |  |
| Yes | No | No | No | Yes | No |  |
| No | No | Yes | Yes | No | Yes |  |
| No | No | No | No | Yes | Yes |  |
| No | No | No | Yes | No | Yes |  |

I want to fill the column 'TREATED' with 'True' if specific combinations of antibiotic columns contain 'Yes.' If the conditions aren't met, then I would like to fill the 'TREATED' column with a 'False' value.

> If ['AZITH'] & ['CLIN'] == 'Yes' |
>
> ['AZITH'] & ['CFTX'] & ['CLIN'] == 'Yes' |
>
> ['AZITH'] & ['CFTX'] & ['METRO']== 'Yes' |
>
> ['AZITH'] & ['CFTN']  == 'Yes' |
>
> ['CFTX']  & ['DOXY'] & ['METRO']== 'Yes' |
>
> ['CFTN']  & ['DOXY'] == 'Yes' |
>
> ['DOXY']  & ['METRO']== 'Yes' ,
>
> Then return 'True' in column 'TREATED'
>
> Else 'False'

What I had in mind was some sort of if statement or use of lambda function, however, I am having trouble.

This must not be exclusive to the above combinations but also include for example if all 6 medications were given. If that's the case, then 'True' should be returned because the condition has been met to give at least 2 of the treatment medications.

The desired output is below:

| AZITH | CLIN | CFTX | METRO | CFTN | DOXY | TREATED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | Yes | No | No | No | No | Yes |
| No | Yes | No | Yes | No | No | No |
| Yes | Yes | No | No | No | No | Yes |
| No | No | No | No | No | No | No |
| Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | **Yes** |
| No | Yes | Yes | Yes | No | Yes | **Yes** |
| No | No | No | No | No | Yes | No |
| No | No | No | No | No | No | No |
| Yes | Yes | Yes | No | No | No | Yes |
| Yes | No | Yes | Yes | No | No | Yes |
| Yes | No | No | No | Yes | No | Yes |
| No | No | Yes | Yes | No | Yes | Yes |
| No | No | No | No | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| No | No | No | Yes | No | Yes | Yes |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "AZITH": [
            "Yes",
            "No",
            "Yes",
            "No",
            "Yes",
            "No",
            "No",
            "No",
            "Yes",
            "Yes",
            "Yes",
            "No",
            "No",
            "No",
        ],
        "CLIN": [
            "Yes",
            "Yes",
            "Yes",
            "No",
            "Yes",
            "Yes",
            "No",
            "No",
            "Yes",
            "No",
            "No",
            "No",
            "No",
            "No",
        ],
        "CFTX": [
            "No",
            "No",
            "No",
            "No",
            "Yes",
            "Yes",
            "No",
            "No",
            "Yes",
            "Yes",
            "No",
            "Yes",
            "No",
            "No",
        ],
        "METRO": [
            "No",
            "Yes",
            "No",
            "No",
            "Yes",
            "Yes",
            "No",
            "No",
            "No",
            "Yes",
            "No",
            "Yes",
            "No",
            "Yes",
        ],
        "CFTN": [
            "No",
            "No",
            "No",
            "No",
            "Yes",
            "No",
            "No",
            "No",
            "No",
            "No",
            "Yes",
            "No",
            "Yes",
            "No",
        ],
        "DOXY": [
            "No",
            "No",
            "No",
            "No",
            "Yes",
            "Yes",
            "Yes",
            "No",
            "No",
            "No",
            "No",
            "Yes",
            "Yes",
            "Yes",
        ],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
mask = (
    ((df["AZITH"] == "Yes") & (df["CLIN"] == "Yes"))
    | ((df["AZITH"] == "Yes") & (df["CLIN"] == "Yes") & (df["CFTX"] == "Yes"))
    | ((df["AZITH"] == "Yes") & (df["CFTX"] == "Yes") & (df["METRO"] == "Yes"))
    | ((df["AZITH"] == "Yes") & (df["CFTN"] == "Yes"))
    | ((df["CFTX"] == "Yes") & (df["DOXY"] == "Yes") & (df["METRO"] == "Yes"))
    | ((df["CFTN"] == "Yes") & (df["DOXY"] == "Yes"))
    | ((df["DOXY"] == "Yes") & (df["METRO"] == "Yes"))
)
df.loc[mask, "TREATED"] = "Yes"
df = df.fillna("No")
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output
   AZITH CLIN CFTX METRO CFTN DOXY TREATED
0    Yes  Yes   No    No   No   No     Yes
1     No  Yes   No   Yes   No   No      No
2    Yes  Yes   No    No   No   No     Yes
3     No   No   No    No   No   No      No
4    Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes  Yes  Yes     Yes
5     No  Yes  Yes   Yes   No  Yes     Yes
6     No   No   No    No   No  Yes      No
7     No   No   No    No   No   No      No
8    Yes  Yes  Yes    No   No   No     Yes
9    Yes   No  Yes   Yes   No   No     Yes
10   Yes   No   No    No  Yes   No     Yes
11    No   No  Yes   Yes   No  Yes     Yes
12    No   No   No    No  Yes  Yes     Yes
13    No   No   No   Yes   No  Yes     Yes
```

Comment: Thank you, I received the following error unfortunately with the last line:
Cannot setitem on a Categorical with a new category (No), set the categories first. I will give @mozway's set a try as well.

Comment: Okay, I was able to work around this issue by setting everything in the 'TREATED' column df['Treated'] = 'No' to remove the 'NaN' and then using df.loc[mask, "TREATED"] = "Yes" so that I can ommit using df.fillna. Thanks for the help @Laurent.

Comment: Right, that was the way to go. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little abstract but you can use bit flag to represent each Yes (True) assign it a binary value and then do the math in threated based on an if statement.

https://dietertack.medium.com/using-bit-flags-in-c-d39ec6e30f08

Answer (score 0):

You can use set operations, first aggregate as the sets of given medications, then check over all possible combinations if you have a superset:

```
valid_treatments = [{'AZITH', 'CLIN'}, {'AZITH', 'CFTX', 'CLIN'},
                    {'AZITH', 'CFTX', 'METRO'}, {'AZITH', 'CFTN'},
                    {'CFTX', 'DOXY', 'METRO'}, {'CFTN', 'DOXY'},
                    {'DOXY', 'METRO'},
                   ]

def is_valid(row):
    combination = set(df.columns[row])
    return 'Yes' if any(
               combination.issuperset(v)
               for v in valid_treatments
           ) else 'No'

out = df.assign(TREATED=df.eq('Yes').apply(is_valid, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   AZITH CLIN CFTX METRO CFTN DOXY TREATED
0    Yes  Yes   No    No   No   No     Yes
1     No  Yes   No   Yes   No   No      No
2    Yes  Yes   No    No   No   No     Yes
3     No   No   No    No   No   No      No
4    Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes  Yes  Yes     Yes
5     No  Yes  Yes   Yes   No  Yes     Yes
6     No   No   No    No   No  Yes      No
7     No   No   No    No   No   No      No
8    Yes  Yes  Yes    No   No   No     Yes
9    Yes   No  Yes   Yes   No   No     Yes
10   Yes   No   No    No  Yes   No     Yes
11    No   No  Yes   Yes   No  Yes     Yes
12    No   No   No    No  Yes  Yes     Yes
13    No   No   No   Yes   No  Yes     Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is going to attempt to vectorize this solution. But I got the idea for the superset from Mozway. Before that I couldn't figure out how to handle all combos

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame({ "AZITH": ["Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","No","No",],
"CLIN": ["Yes","Yes","Yes","No","Yes","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","No","No","No","No",],
"CFTX": ["No","No","No","No","Yes","Yes","No","No","Yes","Yes","No","Yes","No","No",],
"METRO": ["No","Yes","No","No","Yes","Yes","No","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes",],
"CFTN": ["No","No","No","No","Yes","No","No","No","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No",],
"DOXY": ["No","No","No","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","No","No","No","Yes","Yes","Yes",]})
combos = np.array([[1,1,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,1,0,1],[0,0,0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1,0,1]])
df = df.replace("Yes",1)
df = df.replace("No",0)
c = []
for l in range(len(combos)):
    c.extend(itertools.combinations(range(len(combos)),l))
all_combos = combos
for combo in c[1:]:
    combined = np.sum(combos[combo,:],axis=0)
    all_combos = np.vstack([all_combos,combined])

all_combos[all_combos!=0]=1
all_combos = np.unique(all_combos,axis=0)
combo_sum = all_combos.sum(axis=1)
all_combos[all_combos==0]=-1
new_df = df.dot(all_combos.transpose())
for i,x in enumerate(combo_sum):
    new_df.loc[new_df[i]<x,i] = 0

new_df[new_df>0]=1
new_df["res"] = new_df.sum(axis=1)
new_df.loc[new_df.res>0,"res"] = True
new_df.loc[new_df.res==0,"res"] = False
df["res"] = new_df["res"]
```

```
    AZITH  CLIN  CFTX  METRO  CFTN  DOXY    res
0       1     1     0      0     0     0   True
1       0     1     0      1     0     0  False
2       1     1     0      0     0     0   True
3       0     0     0      0     0     0  False
4       1     1     1      1     1     1   True
5       0     1     1      1     0     1  False
6       0     0     0      0     0     1  False
7       0     0     0      0     0     0  False
8       1     1     1      0     0     0   True
9       1     0     1      1     0     0   True
10      1     0     0      0     1     0   True
11      0     0     1      1     0     1   True
12      0     0     0      0     1     1   True
13      0     0     0      1     0     1   True
```

The general explanation of the code is that I create a numpy array of all combos including combinations of combos (sum of two or more combos) that are acceptable. I delete duplicate combinations and this is what is left

```
np.unique(all_combos,axis=0)
Out[38]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Any extra medications that are not part of the combo are penalized by setting the value to -1 in the combo list. (If extra medications are not to be penalized then the superset is not needed, you can just compare to a sum of the original combos variable.)

A dot product between the dataset and the set of all combos is then done and the value is compared against the sum of the combo (prior to replacing the 0s with -1s). This means if the value is 3 and the expected outcome of the combo is 3, then it is a valid combo. Below is the sum of the combos as an array

```
ipdb> combo_sum
array([2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5,
       5, 6])
```

```
ipdb> new_df
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ...  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
0   -2  -2  -2  -2  -2   0   0   0   0   0  ...   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
1   -2   0   0   0   0  -2  -2   0   0   0  ...   0   2   2   0   0   0   2   2   2   2
2   -2  -2  -2  -2  -2   0   0   0   0   0  ...   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
3    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   -2  -2   0   0   2  -2   0   2   0   2  ...   2   2   4   0   2   4   2   4   4   6
5   -2   0   0   2   2  -4  -2   0   0   2  ...   0   2   2   0   0   2   2   4   2   4
6    1   1   1   1   1  -1   1   1  -1   1  ...   1   1   1  -1  -1   1  -1   1  -1   1
7    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8   -3  -3  -3  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1   1   1  ...   1   1   1   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
9   -3  -1  -1   1   1  -1  -1   1   3   3  ...  -1   1   1   1   1   1   3   3   3   3
10   0  -2   0  -2   0   2   2   2   0   0  ...   2   0   2   0   2   2   0   0   2   2
11  -1   1   1   3   3  -3  -1   1   1   3  ...  -1   1   1  -1  -1   1   1   3   1   3
12   2   0   2   0   2   0   2   2  -2   0  ...   2   0   2  -2   0   2  -2   0   0   2
13   0   2   2   2   2  -2   0   2   0   2  ...   0   2   2  -2  -2   0   0   2   0   2
```

After the dot product, we replace the valid values with 1 and invalid (less than the expected sum) with 0. We sum on all the combinations to see if any are valid. If the sum of combinations >= 1, then at least one combo was valid. Else, all were invalid.

```
ipdb> new_df
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  ...  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  res
0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    1
1   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    1
3   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
4   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1    1
5   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
6   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
7   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
8   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0    1
9   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    1
10  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    1
11  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    1
12  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    1
13  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    1
```

Replace the final summed column with True or false and apply to original dataframe.